# How to pass parameters to ADF pipeline using .NET SDK

Tags: .net, azure-data-factory

I'm trying to pass the pipeline parameter from my function, but it seems like it still uses just the default value. I'm curious what I'm missing here.

I have my ADF-2 pipeline in place. I have defined a pipeline parameter called **schema**. I'm using this pipeline parameter within my *Copy Data* activity in the query like:

```
...
FROM @{pipeline().parameters.schema}.CUSTOMERS t2
...
```

Everything is working fine when I'm debugging the pipeline (when I'm filling in the correct value). But if I'm calling the pipeline by this piece of code

```
var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>()
{
   {"schema", "fi" }
};

var runResponse = await client.Pipelines.CreateRunWithHttpMessagesAsync(
  remoteControlConfigurations.InitPipeConfigurations.ResourceGroup,
  remoteControlConfigurations.InitPipeConfigurations.DataFactoryName,                                                                                        
  remoteControlConfigurations.InitPipeConfigurations.PipelineName,                                                                          
  parameters: parameters);
```

it fails because the **schema** parameter is empty:

```
... 'Invalid object name '.CUSTOMERS' ...
```

What I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the mystery has been solved. By mistake I didn't run the presented code, but the older version without the parameters. When the correct version has been deployed, everything is working fine.